# Disturbing noises appear when I change the speed of a song

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to change the speed of an audio file, if I do it with unsigned values all is all right, but once I start using double values things get messy, for instance, my code works with all the "x.5" numbers but it doesn't with any other number with decimals and in my case, I want to increase the speed by 1.3 points. But when I do it I can hear the song but it from time to time I hear some disturbing noises.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.util.Date;

    class AcceleratePlayback {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            double playBackSpeed = 1.5;       

            File file1= new File("Sample3.wav");
            File file2= new File("DEF.wav");
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file1);
            AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();

            int frameSize = af.getFrameSize();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[65536];
            int read = 1;
            while( read>-1 ) {
                read = ais.read(b);
                if (read>0) {
                    baos.write(b, 0, read);
                }
            }

            byte[] b1 = baos.toByteArray();
            byte[] b2 = new byte[(int)(b1.length/playBackSpeed)];
            for (int i=0; i<(b2.length/frameSize); i++) {
                int ind=(int)((i*frameSize*playBackSpeed));
                if((ind%2)==1) ind++;
              for (int j=0; j<frameSize; j++) {
                  b2[(i*frameSize)+j] = b1[ind+j];
              }
          }


            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b2);
            AudioInputStream aisAccelerated =
                new AudioInputStream(bais, af, b2.length/frameSize);
            AudioSystem.write(aisAccelerated, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you delete this question and then post it again, verbatim (except for the `2 ^ 16` change I pointed out)? I was mid-way through writing an answer when you did, so I discarded the answer. Deleting questions wastes answerers' time, and reposting them means that the discussion on the question is lost.

Comment: When I look in your profile's questions you have asked the same question three times now..

Answer (score 2):

Skimming your code, it seems you are trying to play the audio faster by selecting only some of the PCM values of the original. This is equivalent to [down-sampling (decimating)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_%28signal_processing%29) the original audio.

The problem with that approach is the treatment of high frequency components of the audio. Your down-sampling will, in effect, incorporate arbitrary parts of the high frequency components: an *aliasing* effect. You need to low-pass filter the audio before (or while) down-sampling.

Explaining *how* you do that low-pass filtering is rather complicated because of the maths involved, as you can see from the linked Wikipedia article, so is unsuitable for this answer. Suffice it to say that the simple approach you have chosen is unsuitable.